# Batch - Move all directories in directory to another

Tags: batch-file, directory

I just try move all directories from directory "D:\Download" to "D:\DownloadArchive"

I try this but doesnt work

```
move /y "D:\Download\*.*"  "D:\DownloadArchive"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "FOR /D" to select only directories. (Disclaimer: untested)

```
FOR /d %1 IN ("D:\Download\*") DO move /y "%1" "D:\DownloadArchive"
```

Comment: This works great. Just keep in mind that the `%1` is actually a call variable. Change it to something such as `%i`. If you're using a batch file, the `%i` will need to be `%%i`.

Comment: @PeteZíťák Read my comment.

Comment: @PeteZíťák Yeah don't use `%1` for what you're trying todo.

Comment: Note "move /y" does not seem to overwrite an existing directory

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution is to use a `FOR` statement to move each file in the directory. A better alternative to `move` is `xcopy` as it allows to over-wright existing files.

For the switches I'm using type `xcopy /?` in an CMD Window.

**From Batch:**

```
FOR /d %%i IN ("D:\Download\*") DO xcopy "%%i" "D:\DownloadArchive" /E /I /Y /S
```

**From CMD:**

```
FOR /d %i IN ("D:\Download\*") DO xcopy "%i" "D:\DownloadArchive" /E /I /Y /S
```